# Preload key requests error with revslider?

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

Currently i am testing my site on Google page speed Insight and i am getting following error in revslider
[image]

In which file i should add `<link rel=preload>` as described [here](https://generatepress.com/forums/topic/preload-key-requests-fonts/).

Answer (score 0):

Just Go to the Header Section of the Page and add the code below :

```
link rel=”preload” href="URL” as=”style”>
```

```
 link rel=”preload” href="URL” as=”font” crossorigin=”anonymous”>
```

Choose any one only, check what works for you.

After that, Clear the Page Cache
Problem Solved.